# Bootstrap tab with thicker border not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap tabs work great, but users want me to increase the thickness of the borders.  But, when I increase the thickness from 1px the active tab ends up with a line on the bottom border.  I tried increasing the thickness of the bottom border on the active tab, but does not hide the line.

```
.nav-tabs {
border-bottom: 3px solid #DDDDDD;
/* works with 1px */
}

.nav-tabs > .active > a {
border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    /* works with 1px */
}
```

The following fiddle show the issue : http://jsfiddle.net/jerrykur/FEuC3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've amended your jsfiddle, is this what you're after?

```
.nav-tabs {
border-bottom: 3px solid #DDDDDD;
/* works with 1px */
}

.nav-tabs > .active > a {
border-bottom: none;
position: relative;
top: 3px;

    /* works with 1px */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FEuC3/2/

Comment: This leaves the focus and hover states out of alignment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FEuC3/4/ there you go, doesn't leave anything out of alignment now

Comment: This is not really what I want.  If you set the border width to 1 on the original you will see that the bottom border of the active tab is hidden.  I want to hide the bottom border with a thicker border.

Comment: Andrew, that looks great. I accepted this answer. Could you explain to me what is going on with padding and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: it's actually the margin-bottom: -3px; that's fixing the issue on the .nav-tabs > li class, i added in the padding just so i could visually see it a little better. What it's doing is it's essentially 'raising' the border underneath it by 3px so that the a href covers it, hence why you see no border on open tabs now! hope that explained it a bit!

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the tab down a bit further so that it will cover the line. This will work so long as the bottom border is not too thick. (You will notice the active tab will not stay in line with the other tabs)

```
.nav-tabs > .active.active {
    position: relative;
    top:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the margin-bottom for the active class.

```
.nav-tabs>.active>a,
.nav-tabs>.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
   margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

You may or may not want to use the :hover and :focus, too.

Comment: Maybe there is something missing, but this does not seem to hide/cover the bottom border of the active tab

Comment: @JerryKur, okay. I removed the li and it seems to work with you jsfiddle example now.